# How to resolve 'Couldn't get post build model' error when launching Android app on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

05/26 16:13:46: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro.

Couldn't get post build model. Module: HitachiMMSCRM.app.main Variant: debug

Open logcat panel for Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro (9442e631)

When i try to run my android app using USB debugging ,I got the error where I mentioned above.

I changed my gradles and updated my Sdk in Andorid studio ,but not my project get conected. So  Kindly give any  Solution for this,.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.